# Grid axis is off in Illustrator? Not Vertical or Horizontal aligned with ruler

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I'm slightly new at AI. This is a new issue that I began to see today. It appears that the grid is not 100% Horizontal/Vertical with the ruler. So my objects are snapping to those angles.. reflecting and rotating are affected.

I browsed through my preferences but I could use some direction with this fix.
Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reset the **Constrain Angle** in the `Preferences`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the lightning response. My Constrain Angle was at 150.

Comment: Great! If this solved it for you, be certain to click the little checkmark to the left of the answer to mark it correct.